# Devise edit user changes link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I visit the devise edit user page this URL is users/edit/ however when I lets say change the password and update, the user gets redirected to /users/ where the edit page is now rendered, and if I for instance wrote the current password wrong, it displays that error. How can I make Devise stay at /users/edit if a current password is wrong, or if a field is blank and not redirect to /users/ when clicking the update button?

Comment: I'll be bumping this day'n night. Come on smart geniuses! Help me out here!

Answer (score 0):

You're in the update action of your controller, but rendering the edit partial.

It's not just devise that does this - if you make your own model with validtions, and go to the edit page, make an edit that fails the validations, you'll see that the url loses the /edit.

Comment: Well how do big website companies fix this, how can I keep the errors in the /users/edit/ URL . With Devise?

Comment: Would really appreciate some help here! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer on the Devise github page:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2242